# problem with flex output with decimal numbers

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am programming a small floating numbers calculator in Flex and Bison. So far my code is the following:
Flex code

```
%{
# include "prb1.tab.h"
float yylval;
%}

%%
"+" { return ADD; }
"-" { return SUB; }
"*" { return MUL; }
"/" { return DIV; }
"|" { return ABS; }
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? { yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n { return EOL; }
[ \t] { /* ignore whitespace */ }
. { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
yywrap()
{
}
/*main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int tok;
 while(tok = yylex()) {
 printf("%d", tok);
 if(tok == NUMBER) printf(" = %f\n", yylval);
 else printf("\n");
 }
```

}*/

Bison code

```
/* simplest version of calculator */
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token EOL
%%
calclist: /* nothing */
| calclist exp EOL { printf("= %f\n", $2); }
;
exp: factor
| exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;
factor: term
| factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
;
term: NUMBER
| ABS term { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
;
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

The problem that I have is when I run the program the answer is still in integer. How can I change it to display the answer as a floating point number?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly declare a semantic value type, bison/yacc assume that semantic values have type `int`. Declaring `yylval` in your flex file does not change anything, since bison never sees that file. (It leads to undefined behaviour, though, since `yylval` ends up being declared with two different types. I would gave expected the compiler ti complain about that.)

You can declare a semantic value type in your bison file like this:

```
%define api.value.type {double}
```

(I used `double` because it is almost certainly what you want; `float` is a low-precision datatype which should only be used if you have a good reason.)

You should also remove the declaration of `yylval` from your flex file, since it will be declared in the header file generated by bison.

See the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Value-Type) for more details and code examples.

Comment: thanks @rici, but in which part I should put the define.api.value? because I got the following error syntax.error, undefined {...}

Comment: Anywhere in the declaration section. After `%}` and before `%%`. See bison manual for examples.

Comment: @little: see above. Do not use the `-y` flag when you invoke bison. If your bison version is very old, update it :-) or see the link in my answer for an alternative approach using a preprocessor macro.